# Protractor fails to find Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, jasmine, protractor

I can't seem to get Protractor to realize that Angular is loaded and running. When it opens Chrome my app loads fully in the browser, so I know that Angular is loaded and running correctly.

The config file:

```
exports.config = {
seleniumServerJar: 'C:/Dev/PrismWeb/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar',

seleniumPort: null,

chromeDriver: 'C:/Dev/PrismWeb/selenium/chromedriver.exe',

seleniumArgs: [],

seleniumAddress: null,

allScriptsTimeout: 110000,

specs: ['c:/dev/prismweb/test/e2e/*.js'],

capabilities: {'browserName': 'chrome'},

baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080',

rootElement: 'html',

jasmineNodeOpts: {
    onComplete: null,
    isVerbose: true,
    showColors: true,
    includeStackTrace: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
}
};
```

I've only got one test that I am trying to run and it fails because Protractor can't find Angular.

The Test:

```
describe('homepage loads: ', function(){
var ptor;

    ptor = protractor.getInstance();

    beforeEach(function(){
        ptor.get('/');
    });

it('should load the prism homepage: ', function(){
    var usernameField = ptor.findElement(protractor.By.id("username"));
    //expect(usernameField).toBeDefined();
});
});
```

This is the error I get:

> UnknownError: javascript error: angular is not defined   (Session
>   info: chrome=30.0.1599.69)   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.2,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The
>   server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or
>   timeout: 19 milliseconds Build info: version: '2.35.0', revision:
>   'c916b9d', time: '2013-08-12 15:42:01' System info: os.name: 'Windows
>   7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_21'
>   Session ID: 1ef7dcd7c5fc9c4e9e1dede050002adf Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Capabilities [{platform=XP,
>   acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=chrome,
>   chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.2}, rotatable=false,
>   locationContextEnabled=true, version=30.0.1599.69,
>   cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true,
>   browserConnectionEnabled=false, webStorageEnabled=true,
>   nativeEvents=true, applicationCacheEnabled=false,
>   takesScreenshot=true}]

I've tried moving the ng-app attribute to the body tag (and changing the config accordingly) but I got the same error. We also have an ng-controller attribute on the html tag, and I tried moving that to the body and leaving the ng-app attribute alone on the html tag, but the result was the same. Does anybody have any insight as to why this fails?

EDIT:
Just a couple of notes that might help. I've updated the test above to include the manual bootstrapping efforts. The script tags for Angular and all of the modules are located at the bottom of the page, right before the closing BODY tag. The HTML tag still has the ng-app="myApp" attribute plus the ng-controller="baseController" attribute. If I try to bootstrap the app manually in the test, I get the following:

```
ReferenceError: angular is not defined
```

One other thing that worries me is that one of the modules we use absolutely needs "$" to be mapped to jQuery, so we map it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $jq=jQuery.noConflict();
    var $=jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

Where the ng-app is included:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="prismApp" ng-controller="baseController">
<head>
```

Comment: Do you do your own bootstrapping at all when loading Angular?

Comment: In the tests, no. I'll give that a whirl.

Comment: No, you shouldn't need to do your own bootstrapping - that is just a potential cause of issues. Could you share a snippet of your template? Where the ng-app is loaded?

Comment: The ng-app is on the HTML tag (see my edits above.) The template is just HTML with a couple of ng-* attributes on buttons/fields in a basic login form. We use Bootstrap, but I don't see how that would make any difference.

Comment: You shouldn't need to manually bootstrap it, just as @Jmr said. Are you sure your server is serving up the `angular.js` (or `angular.min.js`) file?  And that your index page is including it in the script?  It seems like the angular source code isn't available to selenium when it loads the page into the browser...

Comment: RE: the "are you sure..." bit... read the initial post. I think this is a timing issue more than anything else. The impression I got from the docs was that I wouldn't have to wait for Angular to load. At this point I am having a hard time believing that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not too sure about doing a `beforeEach()` within a, `it()` but that aside, have you tried waiting a while?
Obviously by this i mean either a `ptor.waitForAngular()` or a `ptor.wait()`?

Try a `ptor.sleep(10000)` after your `ptor.get()` just to see if it is a timing thing.

Edit: also take a look at the [protractor api](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/api.md) and how `wait()` works:

```
ptor.wait(function () {
  // Return a condition. Code will continue to run once it is true      
}, 10000); // Only do this for 10 seconds
```

Edit: Try `ptor.driver.get('my-page');` instead of `ptor.get('my-page');`

Edit: Protractor now exposes `browser` as a global so you can just use `browser.get('index.html#/foo')` or `browser.wait()` etc.

Comment: Sorry about the bad test... I have corrected that. Still runs like before though. With the addition of the sleep() it now sits quietly for 10 seconds before I get an error thrown, the root of which is that it still can't find Angular. I'm really beginning to hate Protractor.

Comment: I came across this issue when i was manually bootstrapping an app. You say you are not though. I ended up using `ptor.driver.get('my-page');` instead of `ptor.get('my-page');`
I updated my answer.

Comment: I feel dirty having done it, but it does work. Final PASSING test suite looks like this:

describe('homepage loads: ', function(){
    var ptor;
    ptor = protractor.getInstance();
    ptor.driver.get("http://prism:8080/index.html");

    it('should load the prism homepage: ', function(){
        var usernameField = ptor.findElement(protractor.By.id("username"));
        expect(usernameField.getText()).toEqual("");
    });
});

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Try including this in your test file:

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
```

It switches off your test's sync with angular and makes it work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ng-app to bootstrap your Angular application? Or are you manually bootstrapping your application?

I see that in your configuration file that `rootElement` is set to 'html'.

By default protractor assumes that the root of the app will be on the body tag. If the `<html>` tag is not where angular bootstraps in your application, try changing the root element in the config file to where angular first bootstraps(wether it is manually or though using the ng-app directive). This really helps with timing issues, and speeds protractors execution up.

Comment: Two points: First, this question is 9+ months old, and Protractor has had many iterations since then; and Second, I had already tried your suggestion and it did not work. Also, making that blanket assumption about where the ng-app attribute will be is faulty as Angular allows it to be most anywhere but prefers it to be on either HTML or BODY. If I set it to BODY then protractor had damn well better look for it there and use it if it finds it. In my case, that was not happening.