# How to locate [(ngModel)] for protractor tests

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor, e2e-testing

```
<span class="selector-label">Team: </span>
<select class="selector-component" [(ngModel)]="selectedTeamId">
  <option *ngFor="#team of teams" [value]="team.id">{{team.name}}</option>
</select>
```

I am trying to add protractor tests for the selectedTeamId which is the first one sorted alphabetically if one user assigned to multiple teams. I think I should use [(ngModel)]="selectedTeamId", but not sure how to do it.  thanks. 
I know how to get all teams, but I need to get the first one which is the logical implemented in selectedTeamId method.

Answer (score 0):

The idea would be to locate the `select` element (by the preceding label, for example), [evaluate](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.evaluate) `teams`, [sort it alphabetically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/979289/771848) by `name`, get the first team and check that this is the same as the `selectedTeamId` model value:

```
var select = element(by.xpath("//span[starts-with(., 'Team')]/following-sibling::select"));

select.evaluate("teams").then(function(teams) {
    teams.sort(function(a, b) {
         return a["name"].localeCompare(b["name"])
    });
    var firstTeam = teams[0];

    expect(select.evaluate("selectedTeamId")).toEqual(firstTeam);
});
```

Comment: HI, alecxe. Thanks for reply. I followed your idea and did some changes, but It did not work. I got "unknown error: angular is not defined" error. I did not use xpath to find "select" element, I used the following one instead. and I know which team will be the first team and just pass in as the expected . So the code is like the following, but it do not work, so what i missed. var select = element(by.css('team-selector select')); expect(select.evaluate("selectedTeamId")).toEqual('ExpectedFirstTeam');

Comment: @qunzi well, "angular is not defined" sounds like a separate problem most likely related to timing issues. Please see if these threads would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28415318/angular-is-not-defined-error-while-executing-protractor-test-on-angular-applic, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391813/protractor-fails-to-find-angular.

Comment: Based on Julia Ralpha air show, looks like Protractor did not support these new angualr 2 directives yet.